# Typescript missing properties TS2012

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, typescript

I have two objects in two separate files:

```
import FooResults = require('fooresults');
class FooViewModel {
    Results = ko.observable<FooResults[]>();
}
export = FooViewModel;
```

And:

```
class FooResults {
    Id = ko.observable<number>();
    Text = ko.observable<string>();
}
export = FooResults;
```

But `FooViewModel` complained about private access, so I switched to an interface.

```
import FooResults = require('fooresults');
class FooViewModel {
    Results: KnockoutObservable<IFooResults[]> = ko.observable<FooResults[]>();
}
export = FooViewModel;
```

And:

```
class FooResults implements IFooResults {
    Id: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable<number>();
    Text: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>();
}
export = FooResults;
```

With:

```
declare interface IFooResults {
    Id: KnockoutObservable<number>;
    Text: KnockoutObservable<string>;
}
```

However now the complier complains when compiling `FooViewModel`, saying it cannot convert `FooResults` to `IFooResults` (despite `FooResults` compiling fine to `js`).

Whats wrong? Thanks.

Edit: Here is the actual error...

```
/*

Compile Error. 
See error list for details
 D:/MyWebProject/Scripts/fooviewmodel.ts(18,4): error TS2012: Cannot convert 'KnockoutObservable<FooResults[]>' to 'KnockoutObservable<IFooResults[]>':

    Call signatures of types 'KnockoutObservable<FooResults[]>' and 'KnockoutObservable<Symology.Insight.ViewModels.StreetWorks.Works.IFooResults[]>' are incompatible:

        Type 'FooResults' is missing property 'Id' from type 'IFooResults'.

        Call signature expects 0 or fewer parameters.


*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've removed the class and just used the interface as the type. Also switched to `observableArray`.

```
class FooViewModel {
    Results = ko.observableArray<IFooResults>();
}
export = FooViewModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the error is elsewhere. The following code segment compiles perfectly fine :

```
/// <reference path="./knockout.d.ts" />

class FooResults {
    Id = ko.observable<number>();
    Text = ko.observable<string>();
}

class FooViewModel {
    Results = ko.observable<FooResults[]>();
}
```

where `knockout.d.ts` is from https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/knockout/knockout.d.ts

PS: That said it is favorable to use `observableArray`.

Comment: The problem was AMD modules not liking me using a private class. My answered solved it later, where I used an interface instead.